# Not booting into Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux

So I attempted to install Arch on a new SSD (on an old computer) and when I rebooted, it didn't accept the drive's boot loader, so I was unable to boot from the new installation at all. I then reinstalled it and tried it again with no luck. I then considered it may be an issue with the partition table (was GPT), so I created a new one with msdos (using a Ubuntu live CD) and tried again, only for it to show the same symptoms.

I then decided to try installing Ubuntu and after rebooting, I was able to boot into the Ubuntu instance just fine. I am wondering what other steps I can troubleshoot to see what may cause the drive not to boot into Arch? I have installed Arch many times on Virtualbox with success.

Comment: Did you install GRUB?

Comment: Yep. Grub was definitely installed and configured.